# What's the state-of-the-art for p-median problem?

Tags: operations-research

I am reading work on the famous p-median problem, like A survey of metaheuristic approaches. I understand the Greedy heuristic is often taken as the baseline algorithm.

I want know what is the state-of-the-art algorithm for p-median problem. If I am going to only implement 3 algorithms, which three you would recommend?

Comment: http://dx.doi.org.sci-hub.bz/10.1016/j.ejor.2005.05.034

Comment: I'm wondering if your interest in implementation is focused on the best fast median algorithms.   Or is it rather a comparison of naive algorithms to sophisticated ones.